# Jquery autosuggest with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement a way in which auto suggest would work with dynamically added input boxes. Everything is working fine with the static input types. i am able to request and retrieve result through ajax with static input types. But when i am trying to do the same thing with the dynamic inputs it is not working here is my code. any help would be appreciated.

```
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.autoSuggest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){
    var rows = 0;

    jQuery('#addRow').click(function(){
        jQuery('#userRows').append('<div class="userRow"><input type="text" name="users['+rows+'][name]" /><input type="text" name="country" id="inputBox" /><input type="text" name="id-holder" id="id-holder"> <input type="text" id="price" name="users['+rows+'][price]" /><a href="javascript:;" class="removeRow">Remove</a> name="users['+rows+'][name]"<div>');
        rows++;
        location.reload();
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.removeRow', function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.userRow').remove();
    });

    // Below just used to show the string on submit

});
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  <?php
  $pluginConf = "";
  if(isset($_GET) && count($_GET) > 0){
       extract($_GET);
  if($limit == "")  $limit = "10";
  if($width == "")  $width = "auto";
$pluginConf = '
$(function() {
  $("#inputBox").autoSuggest({

    ajaxFilePath     : "server.php", 
    ajaxParams       : "dummydata=dummyData",
    autoFill     : "'.$autofill.'",
    iwidth       : "'.$width.'",
    opacity      : "0.9",
    ilimit       : "'.$limit.'",
    idHolder     : "id-holder",
    prices   : "price",
    match        : "'.$match.'"
  });
  alert("Worked");
});';   
   } else {
 $pluginConf = ' 
  $(function() {
    $("#inputBox").autoSuggest({
        ajaxFilePath     : "server.php", 
        ajaxParams   : "dummydata=dummyData", 
        autoFill     : false, 
        iwidth       : "auto",
        opacity      : "0.9",
        ilimit       : "10",
        idHolder     : "id-holder",
        prices   : "price",
        match        : "contains"
    });
    alert("Worked");
  }); ';
 } 

  echo $pluginConf; 
 ?>
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div>
       Item Name @  Price
    </div>
<form  method="post" id="usersForm">
    <div id="userRows">
        <a href="javascript:;" id="addRow">Add Row</a><br />
    </div>


    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

    <!--<input type="text" name="xxx" id="inputBox">
<input type="text" name="id-holder" id="id-holder"> 
<input type="text" name="price" id="price"> -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Describe in detail what you mean by: `it is not working`

Comment: Does autoSuggest work with dynamically generated elements?

Comment: i mean that the autosuggest is not working on  dynamicaly created inputs. when i write into the dynamically created input box it doesn't returns any results.

Comment: @Mike autosuggest isn't working with dynamic elements

Comment: This could be, purely because autoSuggest only attaches its events to inputs on "page load".

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wuyuntao/jquery-autosuggest/blob/master/jquery.autoSuggest.js

Looking at the code, it seems it only attaches these events (focus) to elements that are created on page load.  You would need to write some additional code to add "suggests" to generated input elements.

https://api.jquery.com/on/ use this function.